# Skip Empty Cells in Google Sheets for Text Script with Hyperlink

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, slack

I have a script that I created in Google Apps Script that sends a slack message to a user with certain IDs on a list in a Google Sheet with a hyperlink. The list for each user does not contain the same number of IDs resulting in the hyperlink url for empty cells to appear in the slack message. Is it possible to skip or hide the hyperlink url for cells that are empty for each user. Apologies if this is not clear. Please see payload script below:

```
// custom slack webhook
   var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXSBGW/XXXXXXU1K/XXXXXXXXn9jfZXAAAAAA";
  
  var payload = {
 "channel": "@"+city[2],
 "username": "Alerts",
 "text": "Hi " + city[0] + "\n"+
    "\n Here are your most pending kits for review.\n" + 
    "\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+city[5]+">" +   
    "\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+city[6]+">" + 
    "\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+city[7]+">" + 
    "\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+city[8]+">" +
    "\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+city[9]+">" + 
    "\n Please review these kits as soon as possible.\n" 
  };
```

Generic Hyperlinks provided but basically columns 7 through 9 on the City spreadsheet are sometimes blank. Is it possible to skip these cells if blank or at least not make the url appear? When the cells are blank, usually the hyperlink URL is displayed in the slack message. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each of those values to see if they're populated and only then add them to the message. Multiple ways you can do this, but maybe the most straightforward is to loop through the values, build an array, and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array.

```js
// Example city array
var city = ["name", 1, 2, 3, 4, "city1", "city2", "", "city3"];

// Compile links
var linkStartIndex = 5;
var linkEndIndex = 9;
var links = [];
for (var i = linkStartIndex; i <= linkEndIndex; i++) {
  var value = city[i]
  if (value != null && value != "") {
    links.push("\n <https://google.com/maps/'"+"|"+value+">");
  }
}

// Compile full text
var text = [
  "Hi " + city[0] + "\n",
  "\n Here are your most pending kits for review.\n",
  links.join(""),
  "\n Please review these kits as soon as possible.\n"
];
var joined = text.join("");

console.log(joined);
```

You could potentially make that a little cleaner using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but it all really depends on how your data is structured. Personally, I don't like having a variable number of columns as they doesn't convert as neatly into arrays as variable rows do. I also prefer to work with [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) where possible. Consider how generating this object from your `city` array might make your code easier to comprehend:

```
var record = {
  name: 'Brian',
  slackId: '123',
  cities: [
    'New York',
    'London'
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the loop makes sense!! Relatively new to this and was wondering at what point do I incorporate the payload script to actually send the message through Slack to individual managers? To further expand, my spreadsheet is set up as follows, Col1 (Managers), Col2 (Email Add), Col3 (Slack ID), Col4(Yes or no to send message), Col5(Send via Slack or Email decider), Col6 thru Col15 have City Kit IDs relevant to Managers to review. The list of managers and City Kit IDs can always change and the number of managers and City Kit IDs. Thanks for the help.